# java multi thread to approach mysql

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading

Now, I made a sound searching program.
First, I saved the file path (sound file) in the MySQL DB, then recorded the sound and searched for a matching file comparing the sound fingerprint. But it takes long, because I have a lot of rows (sound files) in the DB. So, here are several questions.

1. I want to connect to the MySQL database to get information using Java
   To increase the speed of the program, I want to use multithreading.
   How can I do that?

   (For example, I want to make the first thread query the first 10 rows,
   and the second the next 10 rows. Approximately, the table has more than
   500 rows.)
2. How can I compare the result of the threads? Can each thread return a value?

Comment: if you only have 500 rows, it's not the number of rows that are getting you, it's the processing of the data.  500 rows in a database is very small.  Look at optimizing your fetch and process code before introducing threading as it will make debugging issues much, much harder later on.

Comment: The bottleneck might exist at several places: 1. Searching rows. Quite unlikely if you have only 500 rows. 2. Transferring your data from the database to the application layer. Quite likely if you load raw sound files from the database. 3. In your application code. Again, likely, unless you precompute fingerprints. Multithreading will bring little, if any benefit in situations 1. or 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TO second point about thread job results you can use `Callable` interface and `ExecutionService` ( are build-in in standard library)

Try this example :
https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/get_netbeans_6